# Obtener ID de una tabla al pulsar en editar

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

¿Cómo puedo obtener el id de esta tabla consultada desde base de datos recorrida foreach solo atrapa el primero?

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Documento</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Correo</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <%
                List<Profesor> voSerVa = servi.query();
                for (Profesor vio : voSerVa) {
                    out.println("<tr >"
                            + "<td><input type='checkbox' value="+vio.getIdProfesor()+"></td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getIdProfesor() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getNombre() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getApellido() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getDocumento() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getTelefono() + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + vio.getCorreo() + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>"
                    );
                }
            %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Cuando la trae llena la tabla pero cuando trato de obtener el id para editar el profesor no me deja o solo me trae el primero como puedo hacer para que cuando le de en el checkbox obtenga el id del profesor y lo pueda tener para editar.

Comment: Yo lo que aria seria primero agregarle una clase a tu checkbox, después les el click y listo

Comment: o tambien '<input type='checkbox' onClick="funcion('+vio.getIdProfesor()+')" value="+vio.getIdProfesor()+">' y ua en tu función la recibes

Comment: Hola BRAYHAN FELIPE, debes aclarar si lo que quieres hacer es en el lado del servidor o del cliente, eso condicionará la pregunta (será JavaScript o Java/JSP, pero no ambas). Dale a [edit] la pregunta para añadir esa información. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour]  para más información.